# android - Which MediaRecorder configuration is supported by all device?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am recording communication voice in my app and I added storage and audio record permission manifest and also getting programmatically.

My code is working fine on one device(Android 6.0 Lenovo K3 Note)
But not on another (Android 8.1 ONEPLUS A5010)

In second device output is saved as a blank file of 3.15KB

I am adding my code which I am using please tell what I am doing wrong.

```
 MediaRecorder mRecorder;
 String mFileName;
```

Code in OnCreate

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "engwingoLastCall.3gp");

                 mFileName = file.getAbsolutePath();

try {
        if(mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Recorder Error:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Methods

```
public void startRecording() {

    try {
        if(mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Recorder", "prepare() failed");

    }


}
public void stopRecording() {

    if(mRecorder != null) {

        try {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are not setting a profile, maybe you need to call setAudioEncodingBitRate, setAudioSamplingRate and setAudioChannels methods too.

Comment: Can you please provide example so that I can test

Comment: Ya that solved my problem...Thanks...you can post answer so that I can accept .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Code was OK but the reason for this behavior of my recorder was,
Some other service also using my recorder at that time and that's why the file was saved empty (3.15KB Size)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not setting a profile with `setProfile()` method you may need to set audio channels, bitrate and sampling rate for audio too. Here is an example:

```
mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
// you would not want to record stereo, it is not logical

mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
// you can set it to 64000 or 96000 to lower quality, therefore decreasing the size of the audio

mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
// AFAIK, default value.
```

Hope this helps.